# How to force a program to write log into standard output In spite of redirection?

Tags: linux, io-redirection

**Background**

Today I am trying perconna's innobackupex with this command:

```
innobackupex --stream=xbstream /root/backup/ > /root/backup/backup.xbstream
```

However, I noticed logs show up on my terminal:

```
...
IMPORTANT: Please check that the backup run completes successfully.
           At the end of a successful backup run innobackupex
           prints "completed OK!".

230202 15:52:24 Connecting to MySQL server host: 127.0.0.1, user: root, password: set, port: 3306, socket: not set
...
```

**Confusion**

Shouldn't the redirection `>` writes the standard output to /root/backup/backup.xbstream?
Why I can still see logs on terminal?

Comment: Does it work if you change `>` into `2>` to redirect the error stream, or is the application writing directly to the terminal device?

Comment: Thank you for replying @Kusalananda. Innobackupex does write logs into stdError. This is still confusing to me, since the logs are not error logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that processes in Unix-like systems have different streams for the output of errors and the processed data: `stderr` and `stdout`. This separation is made to prevent warnings and error messages from disturbing the format of the output data (for example, if it is to be forwarded by a pipe).

```bash
# redirect the command output, but omit warnings and errors
# (these will end up on stderr, which is written to the console by default)
mycommand > /some/path/myfile

# redirect warnings and errors only
mycommand 2> /some/path/myfile

# redirect both
mycommand &> /some/path/myfile
```

Refer to [GNU's official Bash documentation on redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) for more details on redirecting each of those streams.

Comment: Thank you! you are right, innobackupex does write logs into stdError. This is still confusing to me, since the logs are not error logs.

Comment: @SteveWu Anything that is extra to the normal output of the software running without issues could be considered "diagnostic output" and therefore better served on the error stream.

Comment: @SteveWu You're welcome^^ It confused me a bit at the beginning, too, but it's actually quite logical: Imagine you use a tool that generates an image and use a pipe to redirect its output to a hard disk. If an error message came up on the same stream, your image would be corrupted.